# How to override local variable by environment variable

Tags: linux, shell-script, environment-variables

I have one script running in production where one value assigns but i want to use a different value from here.

My script.sh

```
a=20181214

....
```

I was calling this script after `export a=20181212` and then call this script as i want to use `20181212` from this script. 
But each time its picking the value as `20181214`.

Comment: Can you modify the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify the script then modify it so that it says

```
a=${a:-20181214}
```

This would make it use the previously set value of `a`, or `20181214` if `$a` is empty or the variable is unset.  This is [a standard parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

You would then either use

```
export a=20181212
./script.sh
```

or

```
a=20181212 ./script.sh
```

The latter of these avoids setting the variable in the calling environment and only sets it for the script's environment.

If you *can't* modify the script, then the script would always override your `a` value, no matter what you did.  In this case, contact the person who maintains the script and explain the situation.  If worse comes to worse, use a copy of the script that you *can* modify, assuming the script does not expect to be located in a particular location.

Comment: Depending on the interpreter, there are possible hack approaches like with `$BASH_ENV`/`~/.zshenv` where you could add some DEBUG traps, or `bash`'s exported functions where you could redefine a command used in the script to reset the value of the variable to the one the OP wants after it has run the `a=20181214` assignment.

Answer (score 1):

A script will be executed within another shell. And the command `export A` only sets the variable for the current shell.
You could export the variable on top of your script, it wouldn't affect the rest of your environment. Eg

```
~$ export A=a
~$ echo $A
a
```

if you create in the same shell a script test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export A=b
echo $A
```

The output will be 'b', but value of A in the shell remains unchanged